# get data from multiple tables in one sqlite database and sort them by date

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting, cursor

I have a SQLite database contains 4 tables in my android app . each table has a column for saving date .
the other columns are "money" , "description" , "member_id"

now I want to sort all data in these 4 tables by date and show them in a recycler view, but I don't know what to do ?

maybe using some kind of cursor or .....

do you have any idea to solve this problem ?
sorry for not having code to write here

thanks .

Answer (score 1):

> maybe using some kind of cursor or .....

There is a [**`MergeCursor`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html) which would sound ideal. However, the issue is then sorting.

The following SQL, assuming the tables are named **table1**, **table2**, **table3** and **table4**, would merge the 4 tables, sorting by date into a cursor.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 UNION
    SELECT * FROM table2 UNION
        SELECT * FROM table3 UNION 
            SELECT * FROM table4
ORDER BY savedate ASC
```

If the column names were different **BUT in the same order** then the above would just need the ORDER BY ???? ASC to be altered so that ???? reflected the appropriate column as per the first table.

So if your tables were

table1 columns: date1 money1 description member_id1
table2 columns: date2 money2 description member_id2
table3 columns: date3 money3 description id_member3
table4 columns: date4 money4 description4 member4_id

then :-

```
SELECT * FROM table1 UNION
    SELECT * FROM table2 UNION
        SELECT * FROM table3 UNION 
            SELECT * FROM table4
ORDER BY date1 ASC
```

i.e. date1 is the resultant column name for the date field.

You could also use :-

```
SELECT *, date1 AS savedate FROM table1 UNION 
    SELECT *, date2 AS savedate FROM table2 UNION 
        SELECT *, date3 AS savedate FROM table3 UNION 
            SELECT *, date4 AS savedate FROM table4 
ORDER BY savedate ASC
```

In which case savedate is an additional column available in the cursor.

Comment: thanks . in your code savedate (date column) should be have same name  in all tables . yeah ?

Comment: Yes, the above assumes that all the tables have the same column names and that the date column is named savedate. However, having different column names isn't a show stopper you could use `AS` to change them to the same name. e.g. `SELECT *, date1 AS savedate FROM table1 UNION SELECT *, date2 AS savedate FROM table2 UNION SELECT *, date3 AS savedate FROM table3 UNION SELECT *, date4 AS savedate FROM table4 ORDER BY savedate ASC`. Noting that savedate will be a new column available in the cursor (not in any of the tables).

Comment: tnx again its helpful

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look here to make unions between tabels. It is about MySQL, but it works exactly in the same way for SQLite.

[How to merge 2 tables into one result in MySQL](http://www.select-sql.com/mysql/how-to-merge-2-tables-into-one-result-in-mysql.html)

It will give you an example how to select columns from multiple tabels and you could use this approach to generate a cursor for a recyclerview adapter.

Comment: thanks . if date column in table 1 called "date1" and in table 2 "date2" and also for table 3 and 4 . does merging tables work ?